# How to draw multiple bitmaps on a canvas

Tags: android, bitmap, android-canvas

I am having trouble with the canvas function, I have no problem drawing 1 bitmap with the canvas but as soon as I add a 2nd bitmap, it only draws the last bitmap, does not show both.
please help. here is my code.
My intent, is to then animate these 2 different bitmaps independently on the screen.

```
@Override
        protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
          football = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),
                    R.drawable.ballicon);

        receiver = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),
                R.drawable.rec);


       canvas.drawBitmap(football, translate, null);
       canvas.drawBitmap(receiver, translate, null);


        Matrix m = canvas.getMatrix();
        Log.d(DEBUG_TAG, "Matrix: " + translate.toShortString());
        Log.d(DEBUG_TAG, "Canvas: " + m.toShortString());
    }
```

Thanks

Comment: What happens if you draw the bitmaps at different locations as a test?  canvas.drawBitmap(football, 0,0, null);
canvas.drawBitmap(receiver, 100,100, null);

Comment: I agree with slund, where on the code do you draw them in different locations? They both use the same 'translate' Matrix. Draw them in different locations by using different Matricies and if you want to draw them in the same location then give one a lower alpha value in a Paint object so that it can let the other 'bleed' through it.

Comment: ok I see what you mean, I will try that out. Thx!

Answer (score 2):

Here is a canvasview for drawing with multiple bitmaps

```
public class AdvanceCanvasView extends View {
private Bitmap bitmap;
private Canvas bitmapCanvas;
private Bitmap mBitmapBrush;
private ArrayList<Bitmap> bitmapArrayList;
private Vector2 mBitmapBrushDimensions;
private Paint paintLine;
private List<Vector2> mPositions = new ArrayList<Vector2>(100);
private HashMap<Integer, Path> pathMap; // current Paths being drawn
private HashMap<Integer, Point> previousPointMap; // current Points
private int i = 0;

private static final class Vector2 {
    public Vector2(float x, float y) {
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
    }

    public final float x;
    public final float y;
}

@SuppressLint("UseSparseArrays")
public AdvanceCanvasView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs); // pass context to View's constructor
}

public AdvanceCanvasView(Context c) {
    super(c);
    pathMap = new HashMap<>();
    previousPointMap = new HashMap<>();
    bitmapArrayList = new ArrayList<>();
    paintLine = new Paint();
}

@Override
public void onSizeChanged(int w, int h, int oldW, int oldH) {
    bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(getWidth(), getHeight(),
            Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
    bitmapCanvas = new Canvas(bitmap);
}

@Override
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    canvas.drawBitmap(bitmap, 0, 0, null);
    for (int i = 0; i < mPositions.size(); i++) {
        canvas.drawBitmap(bitmapArrayList.get(i), mPositions.get(i).x, mPositions.get(i).y, null);
    }

}

@Override
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
    int action = event.getActionMasked();
    int actionIndex = event.getActionIndex();

    if (action == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN
            || action == MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_DOWN) {
        touchStarted(event.getX(actionIndex), event.getY(actionIndex),
                event.getPointerId(actionIndex));
    }
    else if (action == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP
            || action == MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_UP) {
        touchEnded(event.getPointerId(actionIndex));
    }
    else {
        touchMoved(event);
    }

    invalidate();

    return true;
}

private void touchStarted(float x, float y, int lineID) {
    Path path;
    Point point;
    path = new Path(); // create a new Path
    pathMap.put(lineID, path); // add the Path to Map
    point = new Point(); // create a new Point
    previousPointMap.put(lineID, point); // add the Point to the Map
    path = new Path(); // create a new Path
    point = new Point(); // create a new Point
    path.moveTo(x, y);
    point.x = (int) x;
    point.y = (int) y;

} // end method touchStarted

private void touchMoved(MotionEvent event) {
    // for each of the pointers in the given MotionEvent
    for (int i = 0; i < event.getPointerCount(); i++) {
        final float posX = event.getX();
        final float posY = event.getY();
        mPositions.add(new Vector2(posX - mBitmapBrushDimensions.x / 2, posY - mBitmapBrushDimensions.y / 2));
        bitmapArrayList.add(mBitmapBrush);
    }
    invalidate();

}

private void touchEnded(int lineID) {
    Path path = pathMap.get(lineID);
    path.reset();
}

public void init(Bitmap bitmap) {
    mBitmapBrush = bitmap;
    BitmapShader shader = new BitmapShader(mBitmapBrush, Shader.TileMode.MIRROR, Shader.TileMode.MIRROR);
    paintLine.setShader(shader);
    mBitmapBrushDimensions = new Vector2(mBitmapBrush.getWidth(), mBitmapBrush.getHeight());
}

}
```